# ASP.NET MVC search function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Really needing help.

I have made search function for my web application, but **dropdown** list does not work. Whenever I click "Search" the **DropDownList**  gets back to it's default value ("All") and it doesn't play any role in the search...

Here is my code from controller and the method which is called by the search:
And later on there is the code from View part

```
public ActionResult Index(string title = "", string city = "")
{
    var listOfCities = new List<string>();
    var genreQry = from d in db.Restaurants
                   orderby d.City
                   select d.City;
    listOfCities.AddRange(genreQry.Distinct());
    ViewBag.citiesList= new SelectList(listOfCities);
    var restaurants = from m in db.Restaurants
                      select m;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(city))
    {
        restaurants = restaurants.Where(s => s.City.Contains(city));
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
    {
        restaurants = restaurants.Where(x => x.RestaurantName == title);
    }
    return View(restaurants);
}
```

Code from view:

```
@model IEnumerable<RestaurantsInLithuania.Models.Restaurant>
....
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Restaurants", FormMethod.Get))
{
    City: @Html.DropDownList("citiesList", "All") 
    Title: @Html.TextBox("title") <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" class="whatever" />
}

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RestaurantName)</th>
        ....
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RestaurantName)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TypeOfCuisine)</td> 
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: Create a view model containing properties the selected city, the city options, the title  and the collection of restaurants so that you can strongly bind to your model.

Comment: And your creating a <select>` element named `citiesList` but your parameter is named `city` (the value of `city` will always be `null`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of your dropdownlist *doesn't play any role in the search* because it has a `name="citiesList"` attribute, but the parameter in your method is named `city`. If you change the attribute to `string citiesList` then its value will be bound to the value of the selected option.

However, when you return the view, the selected option in the dropdownlist will still be `"All"` because you are not binding to anything.

Create a view model to represent what you want in the view

```
public class RestaurantVM
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CityList { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Restaurant> Restaurants { get; set; }
}
```

and then in the controller method

```
public ActionResult Index(string title, string city)
{
    var restaurants = from m in db.Restaurants select m;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(city))
    {
        restaurants = restaurants.Where(s => s.City.Contains(city));
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
    {
        restaurants = restaurants.Where(x => x.RestaurantName == title);
    }
    var cities = db.Restaurants.OrderBy(x => x.City).Select(x => x.City).Distinct();
    RestaurantVM model = new RestaurantVM()
    {
        Title = title,
        City = city,
        CityList = new SelectList(cities),
        Restaurants = restaurants
    };
    return View(model );
}
```

and then in the view

```
@model yourAssembly.RestaurantVM
....
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Restaurants", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.City)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.City, Model.CityList, "All")
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title)
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" class="whatever" />
}

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Restaurants.FirstOrDefault().RestaurantName)</th>
            ....
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Restaurants)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.RestaurantName)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.City)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.TypeOfCuisine)</td> 
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```